# Expand a series to a larger dataframe using the index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

df1 is a dataset that has the mean values of CHU for each month of each period. (400 total values)

```
Station Name    Period  Month   CHU
BEAVERLODGE         1   1       1.79704898931554
BEAVERLODGE         1   2       0.1680085712099234
BEAVERLODGE         1   3       4.112437412852452
BEAVERLODGE         1   4       45.52884011661426
BEAVERLODGE         1   5       59.00708544329818
BEAVERLODGE         1   6       55.99191752540373
BEAVERLODGE         1   7       42.66769521104078
BEAVERLODGE         1   8       57.23306311568642
BEAVERLODGE         1   9       78.227061891039
BEAVERLODGE         1   10      47.404451708509015
```

df2 is a larger dataset that has each value of CHU for each month, year, period.
(9000 total values)

```
Station Name    Period  Month   Year    CHU
BEAVERLODGE        1       1    1931    3.997620000000001
BEAVERLODGE        1       1    1943    1.6936199999999983
BEAVERLODGE        1       1    1945    0.45671999999999846
BEAVERLODGE        1       2    1938    10.523399999999997
BEAVERLODGE        1       2    1954    10.285799999999998
BEAVERLODGE        1       3    1930    11.470499999999998
BEAVERLODGE        1       3    1934    7.443599999999996
BEAVERLODGE        1       3    1937    4.80618
BEAVERLODGE        1       3    1939    0.9967199999999985
BEAVERLODGE        1       3    1941    0.8707200000000004
BEAVERLODGE        1       3    1942    2.25
```

For example, in each row of Beaverlodge Month 3 I would like I column with 4.11 . etc..
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did @Tom's answer give you what you need?  Because if not, it's not clear what you're asking for.  Are you looking to change the values within df2, or create an entirely new dataframe?  Providing the desired output would be helpful.

Comment: @elPastor There are different stations and periods in the dataset with respective means of CHU for each month (the CHU column of df1) that I need to put in a column beside the individual monthly values of CHU in df2.

Comment: @Tom Thank you! I'm getting an error " InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects". In series 1 the index is like so (1.0, 1.0, 'BEAVERLODGE') but in series two (1, 1, 'BEAVERLODGE'). I would also like to keep the original CHU column and put a new one for CHUmean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using `map`:

```
s1 = df1['CHU']
s1.index = zip(df1['Period'], df1['Month'])
s2 = pd.Series(zip(df2['Period'], df2['Month']))
df2['CHU'] = s2.map(s1)
```

Giving for `df2`:

```
   Station_Name  Period  Month  Year       CHU
0   BEAVERLODGE       1      1  1931  1.797049
1   BEAVERLODGE       1      1  1943  1.797049
2   BEAVERLODGE       1      1  1945  1.797049
3   BEAVERLODGE       1      2  1938  0.168009
4   BEAVERLODGE       1      2  1954  0.168009
5   BEAVERLODGE       1      3  1930  4.112437
6   BEAVERLODGE       1      3  1934  4.112437
7   BEAVERLODGE       1      3  1937  4.112437
8   BEAVERLODGE       1      3  1939  4.112437
9   BEAVERLODGE       1      3  1941  4.112437
10  BEAVERLODGE       1      3  1942  4.112437
```

**Explanation:**  You create a series `s1` based on `df1` with `(Period, Month)` paris as the index and `CHU` as values.  You also create a series `s2` based on `df2` with `(Period, Month)` pairs as the values.  `map` then uses the values from `s2` to "look up" the desired `CHU` value via `s1`.

I use both `Period` and `Month` because I am assuming there are more than one `Period` you are trying to use to reassign values.  If that isn't the case, you could do a similar approach without using that column.